# Alamofire read header response

Tags: ios, swift3

```
self.manager!.request(url+"ClassStudents/"+(self.id)! + "/Y?pageSize=-1", method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody,headers: headers
                ).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[Student]>) in
                    if (response.result.isFailure){
```

My question here is, I get the response but I need to read a certain value from headers. Like X-Page-Max-Index , how can I read this value from headers.

sthg like

response.headers().get("X-Page-Max-Index")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`allHeaderFields`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/httpurlresponse/1417930-allheaderfields) property of `HTTPURLResponse` for that.

```
print(response.response.allHeaderFields["X-Page-Max-Index"])
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me
`response.response?.allHeaderFields["X-Page-Max-Index"] as! String?`